# How to obtain the same result with Conv1D from Keras 1 with Keras 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I ran the same code (with the same data) on CPU first using keras 1.2.0 and then keras 2.0.3 in both codes keras is with TensorFlow backend.
The problem is from Conv1D, many parameters change and i want to reproduce the same Conv1D from keras 1.2.0. Because i dont have the same results with keras 2.

This was my code on Keras 1:

```py
def core_model_CNN(sequence_input
               ,sequence_length 
               ,vocabulary_size
               ,n_out
                ,embedding_dim 
                ,embedding_matrix
                ,filter_sizes = [1,2,3]
                ,num_filters = 100
                ,drop = 0.1) :
    

    embedding =  Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_size, output_dim=embedding_dim
                           , input_length=sequence_length,weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=False)
                  
    embedded_sequences = embedding(sequence_input)
   


    filter_sizes = filter_sizes
    convs = []
    for fsz in filter_sizes:
        conv = Conv1D(nb_filter=32,
                         filter_length=fsz,
                         border_mode='valid',
                         activation='relu',
                         subsample_length=1)(embedded_sequences)
        pool = MaxPooling1D(pool_length=sequence_length-fsz+1)(conv)
        flattenMax = Flatten()(pool)
        convs.append(flattenMax)

    l_merge = concatenate(convs, axis=1)
    #flatten = Flatten()(l_merge)
    dense1= Dense(300,activation='swish')(l_merge)
    dense1=BatchNormalization()(dense1)
    dense1= Dense(250,activation='swish')(dense1)
    dense1=BatchNormalization()(dense1)
    dense1= Dense(200,activation='swish')(dense1)
    dense1=BatchNormalization()(dense1)
    dense1= Dense(150,activation='swish')(dense1)
    dense1=BatchNormalization()(dense1)
    dense1= Dense(100,activation='swish')(dense1)
    dense1=BatchNormalization()(dense1)
    output = Dense(units=n_out, activation='softmax',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(2),)(dense1)

         
    return output
```

and on Keras 2 it becomes

```py
        conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=params['nb_filter'],
                                      kernel_size=fsz,
                                      padding='valid',
                                      activation='relu',
                                      bias_initializer='zeros',
                                      strides=1)(embedded_sequences)
        pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=sequence_length-fsz+1)(conv)
```

I did my modification following this [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.0.0) but i dont have the same result.

Comment: Hi there. Please provide more details and a MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi i update my question